# for loop: why is i++ slower than i = i + 1 in swift

Tags: performance, for-loop, swift, increment

that is a normal empty loop with a normal increment operator "i++"

```
import Foundation

let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

for var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++ {

}

let timeTaken = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start

println(timeTaken) // 0.0229730010032654
```

but this loop with "i = i + 1" is much faster

```
import Foundation

let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

for var i = 0; i < 1000000; i = i + 1 {

}

let timeTaken = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start
println(timeTaken) // 0.00384700298309326
```

the second loop is 5x - 6x times faster

i understand swift is still in beta and i don't compare it to other languages but that makes no sense for me

Comment: What about preincrement? Is it as slow?

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I'm waiting for someone to replicate the results before upvoting.

Comment: You're not alone. I'm guessing this will be fixed in time. http://www.splasmata.com/?p=2798. Try sticking to objective C for the moment if its really a problem.

Comment: Measuring times like this is rather ridiculous. Lots of things are going on on your computer at the same time. Did you turn optimisation on? Did you perform your measurements more than once?

Comment: Sounds like this belongs on CodeReview.StackExchange.com

Comment: @Ramon, why would it? This question is not about improving working code.

Comment: Could you try this a number of times and paste up the results table? Reverse the order of running the two cases for each test. I'm keen to gauge the statistical significance of the different.

Comment: Isn't `i = i + 1` equal to `++i` rather than `i++`? It is recommended to use `++i`.

Comment: I'm also interested in the result of ++i (preincrement). Also, both should be sent to the main thread in case one was sent to a less .. immediate one.

Answer (score 1):

isnt that a optimizer problem? a fair test world be

```
var i = 0
for j in 1..1000000 {
i++
}

var i = 0
for j in 1..1000000 {
i = i + 1
}
```

Comment: i just wanted to hint for some missing optinizations in for loop,
if you use `i++` and `i = i + 1` not within the INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; INCREMENT/DECREMENT Part of the Lopp there is no difference